# How do you find all the files added to a visual studio project and checked in to TFS from a point in time?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, tfs

How do you get a list of all new files added to a visual studio project and checked in to TFS?  I've tried using TFS sidekicks and view history, but they only show changesets which you have to open up to see the details.  I'm simply after a list of new files in a particular branch.  Thanks

Comment: are you looking specifically for new files (adds) or any and all changes?

Comment: Either would do, but I'm most concerned about the added files because they don't show up in a merged (forward integrated) converted dbp->dbproj project file.

Comment: Which would you be more comfortable with, and application (e.g. command line) solution or a PowerShell solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Powershell version.

`Get-TfsItemHistory "$/Project Name" -r -all -version D06/01/2010~ | Select -Expand Changes | Where {$_.ChangeType.Tostring().contains("Add")} | select-tfsitem | fl Path`

I believe this will require the TFS Power Tools to work.